# Solving a variable for an exponential function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have the following problem:

> A person puts 1,100 dollars in an account that he expects will make 5% interest in periods of three months. He then realizes a year later he was wrong about the interest rate and has $50 less than expected. What is the actual interest rate?

So I was able to get an equation out of that:

$$A_1 = 1100(1 + \frac{0.05}{4})^{4t}$$
$$A_1 - 50 = 1100(1 + \frac{r}{4})^{4t}$$
$$1100(1 + \frac{0.05}{4})^{4t} - 50 = 1100(1 + \frac{r}{4})^{4t}$$

Now there is where I get stuck on how to simplify the equation for r?

Comment: wow what is going on... you denote the interest by $r$? if so what is $t$? and how you got that $4$?

Comment: Note: the second equation should be $A_1 + 50$. Are you allowed to use a calculator/computational device for this?

Comment: I am allowed to use a scientific calculator @platty

Comment: @platty do you understand the first equation? why he divides by 4? and what's $t$?

Comment: There is not enough information.  When does he learn that he has made $\$50$ less than expected?

Comment: Those equations were not given by the problem. I came up with them. I used this equation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pvNI.png

Comment: @DougM My bad, it is a year later he learns that.

Comment: Yes; that's the [standard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Calculation_of_compound_interest) for compound interest; $4$ is the number of times per year interest is compounded

Comment: I understand it now! you didn't say when he gets the interest

Comment: Note: $t$ shouldn't be a variable, since you know when he finds out. Plugging in appropriately should give you a constant on the LHS and an expression in terms of $r$ on the RHS you can solve for.

Comment: Isn't t=1 then?

Comment: in that case  $t = 1$ in your calculations above and  $1100(1 + \frac{0.05}{4})^{4} - 50 = 1100(1 + \frac{r}{4})^{4}$ find the number on the left.  Divide through by $1100,$ and take the $4^{th}$ root of both sides.

Comment: this is an investment question see: http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/continuouscompounding.asp and the likes on investopedia. http://www.investopedia.com/articles/basics/04/102904.asp may also be of interest ( no pun intended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for $r$ which makes $$f(r,t)=1100\left(1 + \frac{0.05}{4}\right)^{4t} - 50 - 1100\left(1 + \frac{r}{4}\right)^{4t}=0$$ The solution  depends on $t$.

There is no explicit solution of this equation except if $t=1$ (just as Doug M commented) and numerical methods are required. This would be "simple" since the solution should be "close" to $r=0.05$ if $t$ is sufficiently large (as it uses to be in investment problems).

Assuming it (and making all numbers rational), we can use Taylor series limited to first order and get as a very first approximation $$r=\frac 1 {20}-\frac{2^{16 t-5} \left(\frac{81}{5}\right)^{1-4 t}}{11 t}\tag 1$$ Better would be the simplest Padé approximant which would give $$r=\frac 1 {20}-\frac{81\ 2^{16 t-1} 5^{4 t-1}}{\left(176\ 81^{4 t}-2^{16 t+2} 5^{4 t}\right)
   t+2^{16 t} 5^{4 t}}\tag 2$$ But the rigorous way would be to use a numerical method (such as Newton) starting using $r_0=0.05$.

I give you below a table of results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 t & (1) & (2) & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.0062083 & 0.0054863 & 0.0054795 \\
 2 & 0.0291655 & 0.0287835 & 0.0287805 \\
 3 & 0.0367837 & 0.0365421 & 0.0365404 \\
 4 & 0.0405683 & 0.0404006 & 0.0403994 \\
 5 & 0.0428204 & 0.0426974 & 0.0426966 \\
 6 & 0.044307 & 0.0442135 & 0.0442129 \\
 7 & 0.0453568 & 0.0452838 & 0.0452834 \\
 8 & 0.0461342 & 0.0460761 & 0.0460758 \\
 9 & 0.0467303 & 0.0466834 & 0.0466832 \\
 10 & 0.0471999 & 0.0471616 & 0.0471615 \\
 11 & 0.0475779 & 0.0475463 & 0.0475462 \\
 12 & 0.0478873 & 0.0478611 & 0.047861 \\
 13 & 0.0481444 & 0.0481225 & 0.0481224 \\
 14 & 0.0483605 & 0.048342 & 0.0483419 \\
 15 & 0.0485439 & 0.0485283 & 0.0485283
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

*My previous answer was just stupid ! Not to hide how much it is, I add another one.*

$$f(r,t)=1100\left(1 + \frac{0.05}{4}\right)^{4t} - 50 - 1100\left(1 + \frac{r}{4}\right)^{4t}=0$$

This implies
$$\left(1 + \frac{r}{4}\right)^{4t}=\left(1 + \frac{0.05}{4}\right)^{4t} -\frac 1 {22}$$
$$r=4\left(\sqrt[4t]{\left(1 + \frac{0.05}{4}\right)^{4t} -\frac 1 {22}}-1\right)$$ which is exact.